# How To Utilize Docker Secrets In PHP Code?

Tags: php, docker, docker-swarm

What are the best-practices concerning the usage of docker secrets within a PHP script?

Use case: I've got a Docker stack which is comprised of (1) a **web** service based on an image which couples php with an apache server and (2) a **db** service based on the latest mysql image.

Within /var/www/html on my **web** service, I've got a config.php which defines a number of variables representing database connection parameters (username, password, etc.). This config.php file is included wherever database connections are established throughout the codebase. I have docker secrets defined corresponding to each of the parameters that I want to define in config.php - what is the best way to use those secrets in the definitions in config.php?

By default, each docker secret is mounted to the file `/run/secrets/<secret name>`.

My naive solution was simply to use fopen() and fgets() as follows:

```
function getSecret($secret){
    $secret_file = fopen("/run/secrets/{$secret}");
    $secret = fgets($secret_file);
    fclose($secret_file);
    return  $secret;                      
}
```

config.php:

```
return [
    'database' => [
        'host' => getSecret('db_host'),
        'user' => getSecret('db_user'),
        'password' => getSecret('db_password),
        ...
    ]
];
```

Does this look like a sensible approach?

Comment: What issue have you run into by trying to use secrets with this approach? Do you get a stacktrace? To your application code, the secret basically looks like any other file, so there's nothing fundamentally wrong with using fopen.

Comment: It works, but it was just the first thing that popped into my head and I feel like there must be a more graceful solution. There is a [library on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sadok-f/docker-secrets) that is essentially a more fleshed out version of this. However, I have been considering the possibility of running a bash script from my entrypoint script to translate the /run/secrets files into environment variables so that I can just use getenv() in my PHP code - [something like this](https://medium.com/@basi/docker-environment-variables-expanded-from-secrets-8fa70617b3bc)

Answer (score 5):

I ended up going with `file_get_contents("/run/secrets/...");`

An undocumented 'feature' of this is that by default it adds a newline at the end of the file(`0x0a`), so that needs to be trimmed.

The end result is:

```
$dbpasswd = rtrim(file_get_contents("/run/secrets/mysql_password"));
```

The advantage is that you don't need to deal with opening and closing the file.
The need for trimming is an annoyance though.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php